# Calculating PV system output from Daily global solar exposure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pvlib

I would like to calculate daily PV system energy output in Python and PVLIB from Daily global solar exposure data so I can monitor the performance of a solar PV system i.e. I want to be able to compare the actual energy output of the PV system with a value calculated from the solar exposure data to make sure it is performing well.

Here is an example of the data:
http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/wData/wdata?p_nccObsCode=193&p_display_type=dailyDataFile&p_stn_num=056037&p_startYear=

I've been playing around with [PVlib](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I can't work out which functions to use.

I was hoping I would be able to enter in all the parameters of the PV system into a function along with the solar exposure data and it would give me the predicted energy output.

Comment: A simpler approach will use `data` instead of `calculation`: Instead of trying to compute the expected output, which is not easy predictable, I would suggest to get your production data daily and elaborate a simpler relation between solar exposure and PV production.
Even better is to compare production of your plant with others, I think you can find quite easily production data of other plants in your region.

Answer (score 4):

Well it really depends on how precise you want to be. It's a full time job to design a good algorithm to estimate produced power from only the Global Horizontal Irradiance (GHI - the data you gave).
It depends on the geographical position, the temperature, the angle of your panels, their orientation, their type, the time of day/year, even the electrical installation etc...

However if you're not looking for too much precision, a simple model would be :

- Find an estimation of the efficient of you panels (say 10%)
- Get the area coverage of your panels (in m2), *projected horizontally*.
- Then simply compute `Power = Efficiency * GHI * Area`

You could then refine the model accounting for the angle between you panels and the sun, for example using [pvlib.solarposition.get_solarposition()](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.solarposition.get_solarposition.html).

A few references:
[Computing global tilted irradiance from GHI](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236314649_From_global_horizontal_to_global_tilted_irradiance_How_accurate_are_solar_energy_engineering_predictions_in_practice/link/0c960524c5cabaa5d0000000/download)
[PvLib's cool ModelChain to model precisely you installation](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.modelchain.ModelChain.html#pvlib.modelchain.ModelChain)
[A good overview of most factors impacting you efficiency](https://solargis.com/docs/methodology/pv-energy-modeling)

PvLib's doc is pretty good, have a look at the PvSystem, ModelChain etc...

PS : not enough reputation to add a comment, though I know it doesn't really deserve an answer :/